# Animate point with paper.js

Tags: animation, paperjs

I’d like to rebuild this animation https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHl4Y.jpg in paper.js.

I already tried SVG animations (http://codepen.io/magglomag/pen/jrVwzy) but despite from the fact that they’ll be deprecated soon I was not able to move the two points asynchronously.

What I have so far is the shape and I know that I can animate with the `onFrame` event handler. But I have no clue how to say that the point should animate between the coordinates `[43,168.7]` and `[43,35.3]`.

http://codepen.io/magglomag/pen/yaVXrr

```
var firstSegment = new Segment({
    point: [109,3.7]
});

var secondSegment = new Segment({
    point: [43,168.7]
});

var thirdSegment = new Segment({
    point: [109,202.2]
});

var path = new Path({
    segments: [firstSegment, secondSegment, thirdSegment],
    fillColor: '#2dfd9a',
    closed: true
});

secondSegment.onFrame = function(event) {
  this.point = [43,35.3]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are making is that you are trying to bind an handler to `segment.onFrame` event.
But only [item.onFrame](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#onframe) and [view.onFrame](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#onframe) are available.
In `PaperScript` context, you can even use a global `onframe` named function as a convenient way to animate things.
Here is a simple [example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/fVLBbsIwDP0VqxdgQ6ES4lLEadJuk9A4jh2y1JSI1EZJCkKIf58T1gouq9RGfn62n19zLUi3WFTF5oDR7ItpYbhO8WwGxqOOCBqit5oah1u/pZP2QwwrIDzDWse9+sSmc9qv2V0apvE1cUEegxTRV3CyeFb3YNrngq0xVDAfAK9r2wmyKAdoZ517Y8fSYsRexuIopW6TZTrSK0pDZI9gyUarnZT4EOHIltI3CMjUS//jrHNyNWyics0Gm1YUqlyqjGPC8dMcJth58SuFu45M6izge8LGeJLaCQybC78LKEsSwkDWQfw0TMK1QoezvkBkqLFlCtFnv8m2utecGiXd4nOv+WmFV/hI7suQ+3xluBP4BUpVLiZyzsvlo6BjnUY8ONQn/3Hi/pvzvNzrlj5yU37kfhwyIxTV1/ftFw==) demonstrating how a path segment can be animated.

```
// create a triangle
var triangle = new Path.RegularPolygon({
    center: view.center,
    sides: 3,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange'
});

// store initial first point position
var initialPoint = triangle.firstSegment.point.clone();

// on frame
function onFrame(event) {
    // use sine function as a convenient way to demonstrate animation
    var newPoint = initialPoint + Math.sin(event.count * 0.05) * 30;
    // update first point
    triangle.firstSegment.point = newPoint;
}
```